# Issue on ng add @angular/cli

Tags: angular, angular-cli

When executing `ng add @angular/cli` in root of the project, this error is thrown:

> The package that you are trying to add does not support schematics.
>   You can try using a different version of the package or contact the
>   package author to add ng-add support.

My package.json:

```
{
  "name": "app",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/schematics": "^8.0.0",
    "@angular/animations": "^8.0.2",
    "@angular/cdk": "^8.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "^8.0.2",
    "@angular/compiler": "^8.0.2",
    "@angular/core": "^8.0.2",
    "@angular/fire": "^5.2.1",
    "@angular/forms": "^8.0.2",
    "@angular/material": "^8.0.0",
    "@angular/material-moment-adapter": "^8.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^8.0.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^8.0.2",
    "@angular/router": "^8.0.2",
    "@asymmetrik/ngx-leaflet": "^5.0.2",
    "@ngrx/data": "^8.0.1",
    "@ngrx/effects": "^8.0.1",
    "@ngrx/entity": "^8.0.1",
    "@ngrx/router-store": "^8.1.0",
    "@ngrx/store": "^8.0.1",
    "@ngrx/store-devtools": "^8.0.1",
    "@types/leaflet": "^1.4.7",
    "body-parser": "^1.18.2",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "express": "^4.16.2",
    "firebase": "^6.6.0",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "leaflet": "^1.5.1",
    "leaflet-routing-machine": "^3.2.12",
    "moment": "^2.22.2",
    "rxjs": "^6.3.3",
    "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.800.0",
    "@angular/cli": "^8.0.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^8.0.2",
    "@angular/language-service": "^8.0.2",
    "@ngrx/schematics": "^8.0.1",
    "@types/express": "^4.0.39",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.5.53",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "^5.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
    "karma": "^4.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "ngrx-store-freeze": "^0.2.4",
    "protractor": "^6.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~3.2.0",
    "tslint": "~5.7.0",
    "typescript": "~3.4.5"
  }
}
```

Any hint? Thank you in advance.

Comment: You already have @angular/cli in your project. What are you trying to achieve specifically by adding @angular/cli?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't add @angular/cli to your project, you install it via cmd or command line to your system, and then call it to create and launch apps.

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
ng new my-dream-app
cd my-dream-app
ng serve
```

Here the official docs about angular cli: [Angular Cli](https://angular.io/cli)

Answer (score 0):

It is a strange one... Happened to me as well.

Basically, I just re-installed (updated) the Angular Cli.
Then did the same for firebase-tools.

ng new project
in project root > ng add @angular/fire

At first it gave me another error (didn't document it, wasn't expecting it).
Ran the command again and it responded with:

"The package that you are trying to add does not support schematics. You can try using a different version of the package or contact the package author to add ng-add support."

So I:
1 - Deleted the project.
2 - Rebooted the computer.
3 - ng new'ed anotherProject.

And this time ng add @angular/etc worked fine.

If all else fails, cntrl-alt-del. That probably would have been enough.

Hope the information helps someone (cause I'm sure by now you've rebooted).